# Recover /bin/hostname on AWS AMI

Tags: software-installation, package-management, aws

I have accidently deleted /bin/hostname. Termporarily I have put in a shell script there that returns the known name. But how do I recover the lost binary?

It is an AWS AMI.

```
Linux ip-10-2-0-162 3.4.62-53.42.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 20 07:23:24 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Build another identical instance, copy the file from the working instance?

Comment: @Zoredache I actually do have an identical instance, Thanks!! BTW, this should have been in an "answer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than copying the file from another instance you can also reinstall the package (via `yum reinstall $package`), e.g.:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qf /bin/hostname
net-tools-1.60-110.el6_2.x86_64
[root@localhost ~]# ls -l /bin/hostname
ls: cannot access /bin/hostname: No such file or directory
[root@localhost ~]# yum reinstall net-tools
(...)
Running Transaction
  Installing : net-tools-1.60-110.el6_2.x86_64                                                                                                                           1/1 
  Verifying  : net-tools-1.60-110.el6_2.x86_64                                                                                                                       1/1 

Installed:
  net-tools.x86_64 0:1.60-110.el6_2                                                                                                                                      

Complete!
[root@localhost ~]# ls -l /bin/hostname 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13712 May 10  2012 /bin/hostname
```

Comment: I already fixed my issue but this appears definitely the right approach